# Body overflow-y hidden and scroll inner div only

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div id="main_wrapper">
<header>Header</header>
<div id="inner_wrapper">
    <div id="left_menu">Left menu</div>
    <div id="content_wrapper">
        <div id="inner_content">
            <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
overflow-y: hidden;
}

#main_wrapper {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

header {
width: 100%;
float: left;
background: #0072C6;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px 0;
border-bottom: 7px solid #004477;
}

#inner_wrapper {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

#left_menu {
width: 220px;
float: left;
}

#content_wrapper {
margin-left: 220px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

#inner_content {
width: 100%;
float: left;
background: #999;               
}
```

When the content inside #inner_content div is overflowed, I want to scroll the content only, and let the reamining page in its position.
I know I can do it if I apply position fixed, but I wonder if it can be done with this positioning.

Here is a jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/qJ4qc/

## EDIT

I managed to do this with jQuery like so: http://jsfiddle.net/qJ4qc/2/

Is there a way to accieve this only with css??

Comment: you mean like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/qJ4qc/1/

Comment: no Prakash, I don't want to give specific height to #inner_content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution setting

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ4qc/27/)

Comment: you can't see scroll bar arrow of bottom, it means you won't see entire content of scrolling window, some part at bottom will get cut off(if you have taskbar at bottom of your screen)

Comment: you can set content_wrapper's  height to (100% - height of header), then scroll arrows are showing

Answer (score -2):

```
body {
  height: 90%;
}
```

Keep the height of the body as 90% to avoid clipping of content.

Comment: I would consider having to do things like this to be a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)